# Testing SSH keys authenticates different users depending on directory

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal

I am trying to setup a second git account on my Mac. I've already generated and added the new SSH key to my secondary Github account, and added the new host in `~/.ssh/config` as `github-personal`.  When I test my connection in any directory by doing `ssh -T git@github.com`, it authenticates with the correct first, account. However, when I do `ssh -T git@github-personal`, I expect it to return the name of my second account, but it instead returns the first account. But, I've noticed that if I run the same commands in my `~/.ssh` directory, the correct accounts are returned.

Here are the contents of my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each of those sections - that instructs your SSH agent to ignore any other identities it's loaded, and attempt to use only the specified one.

Your `~/.ssh/config` file would then look something like this:

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `IdentitiesOnly yes` line right at the top of your `~/.ssh/config`. SSH's default is to run through every key in sight, this feels to me like one of those "too late to change it now" choices made in the smaller Internet world of the 1990's.